# JQuery Toggle Class Plus and minus icon issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have Two Divs with popular and others, i'm using jquery toggleClass for slideUp and Slidedown between two div sections currently its working fine but when i click on popular div its showing the contents of popular contents but not changing its icon with **minus to plus** and **plus to minus** vice versa for both divs can somebody help me out in resolving it Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/v9Evw/352/

**Html**

```
<div id="popular">

    <div id="headerDivImg1" class="toggle1" id="popular_img" style='background:#4c97d0;height:30px;width:640px;'>
        <span style='color:#fff;padding-left:10px;line-height:30px;'>DIV1</span>
        <a class="toggle1" style='float:right;' id="popular_img" href="javascript:popular('popular_content', 'popular_img');">

        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="popular_content" class="content" style="display: block;">
        <p>welcome to Div1</p>
    </div>

</div>

<br/>

<div id="others">

    <div id="headerDivImg1" id="other_img" class="toggle2" style='background:#4c97d0;height:30px;width:640px;'>
        <span style='color:#fff;padding-left:10px;line-height:30px;'>DIV2</span>
        <a class="toggle2" style='float:right;' id="other_img" href="javascript:popular('popular_content', 'popular_img');">

        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="other_content" class="content" style="display: block;">
        <p>welcome to Div2</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var $content = $("#popular_content").show();
    $(".toggle1").on("click", function(e)
    {
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
        $content.slideToggle();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var $content = $("#other_content").hide();
    $(".toggle2").on("click", function(e)
    {
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
        $content.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.toggle1
{
    display:inline-block;
    height:27px;
    width:41px;  background:url("minus.png");

}
.toggle1.expanded
{
    background:url("plus.png");
}


.toggle2
{
    display:inline-block;
    height:27px;
    width:41px;  background:url("plus.png");

}
.toggle2.expanded
{
    background:url("minus.png");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help

**HTML**

```
    <div class="div1container">
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus divcontainer" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Div1</div>

    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Div 1 Content
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div2container">
    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus divcontainer" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">Div2</div>

    <div id="demo2" class="collapse">
    Div 2 Content
    </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divcontainer{
    background:aqua;
    width:100%
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.glyphicon-plus').click(function () {
        $(this).parent("div").find(".glyphicon-plus")
            .toggleClass("glyphicon-minus");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you So much Raviteja...Your coding working superbly Just one small request can you place plus/minus symbol to right side and div name on left side in class div1container currently both are on left side Thanks!!!!